# Unknown Error:'<class 'KeyError'>'("The cache has no Package named 'steam')

Tags: apt, steam

Error notifcation in the status menu saying

> An Error occured, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu
>   or apt-get in terminal to see what's wrong. The error message
>   was:'Unknown Error:''("The cache has no Package
>   named 'steam'") This usually means that your installed packages unmet
>   dependencies.

But there aren't any errors or warnings showing up when running apt-get on the command-line. And the notification won't go away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix the problem just run:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall steam
```

The package is only about 800 kB.