# Unknown Error:'<class 'KeyError'>'("The cache has no Package named 'libllvm15:amd64')

Tags: 22.04, linux-headers

after updating packages an error message shows:

```
'<class'keyerror'>'("The cache has no Package named 'libllvm15:amd64'). 
This usually means that your packages have unmet dependencies.
```

Answer (score 3):

Had the same error. Based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756634/unknown-errorclass-keyerrorthe-cache-has-no-package-named-steam), I used the following to fix the issue:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libllvm15
```